# SQL Raw data query

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db

Hi I am trying to query some data like this

```
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM company";

    $stmt = $this->getDbAdapter()->query($sql, \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);

    if ($stmt instanceof \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet) {

        foreach ($stmt as $row) {
            $entities[] =$row;
        }
    }
```

But I get an 500 Internal server error, Is there something wrong with this code?

I have done this one an it work fine.

```
    $sql = "SELECT company.*,address_home.*,address_billing.*, T1.*
           FROM company AS company
           INNER JOIN address AS address_home ON company.address_id_fk = address_home.address_id
           INNER JOIN address AS address_billing ON company.billing_address_id_fk = address_billing.address_id
           INNER JOIN (SELECT  company_id_fk,
                               max(case when company_role_id_fk = '1' then 'true' end) isClient,
                               max(case when company_role_id_fk = '2' then 'true' end) isSupplier
                       FROM company_role_company_maps AS crcm
                       WHERE crcm.company_id_fk = $id
                       GROUP BY company_id_fk) AS T1
           ON(company.company_id = T1.company_id_fk)
           WHERE company.company_id = $id";

    $resultset = $this->getDbAdapter()->query($sql, \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
    $current = $resultset->current()->getArrayCopy();
```

But for some reason when I do the loop i get the error.

I try this to see If I cud catch something.

```
        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM company";

    $stmt = $this->getDbAdapter()->query($sql, \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);

    if ($stmt instanceof \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet) {
        try{
            foreach($stmt as $row) {
                var_dump($row);
            }

        }catch(\Exception $e){
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

But I just got the Internal server error message (There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.)

Comment: What is error in message and in what line is triggered ?

Comment: Looks like you may need to select a database or schema name before or as part of running your query.

Comment: It does not tell me the line it just tells me that is an internal server error 500, the error comes when I do the foreach loop.

Comment: put if(...) in block try{}catch(\Exception $e){ var_dump($e->getMessage();)}  when you print the message copy/paste  here ...

Comment: Its weird because I just get an internal server error 500, Its not even catching anything, please see the code.

Comment: If it is not catching anything the error is not there :) move 
"try{" at beginning pls ....

Comment: The error is exactly on foreach loop, If I comment out the foreach I dont get the error, I also put the try inside the foreach and at the beginning but i got the same result.